# Are there any *very* user friendly (preferably video) explanations of Baum-Welch?

Tags: algorithms, hidden-markov-model

I'd like to understand the Baum-Welch algorithm.  I liked this video on the Forward Backward algorithm:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zDARfKVm7s&feature=related

I'm having trouble coming up with good resources for Baum-Welch.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a video describing hmms
http://videolectures.net/hltss2010_eisner_plm/ (see part 2 of the talk)

Here are many more resources for learning HMMs including a spreadsheet to learn the forward backward algorithm from.

**EDIT:**
I added a pointer to which section of the talk should be viewed.

Comment: So part 2 has the Baum-Welch parameter estimation stuff?  around what minute mark is that?  Thanks

Comment: There should be a link at the bottom of the video player for the part 2 video.  Its long but you should probably watch the whole thing.

Comment: You were right, you do need to watch the whole thing.  This is really good, thanks.  I imagine I will be turning to Jason Eisner if I need more concepts explained.